# Why is this linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Types of ODE**
> For each of the following ODE determine its order, and wheter it is linear or non-linear.

> $$
> \frac{d^3y}{dt^3} + t\frac{dy}{dt} + (\cos t)^2y = 4t^3
> $$

I was given this question to find out the order and decide whether it is linear or non-linear.
The answer provided is third-order and linear. I can understand why it is third-order but don't get why it is linear.
My understanding of a linear equation is shown below:

1. $\cdots + y'' + y' = y$ occur linearly.
2. Coefficient of $y$, $y'$, $y'' + \cdots$ must be the variable it corresponds to.
   For this question, it doesn't meet the first condition where y'' is missing.
   Can someone help?

Comment: The coefficient of $y''$ is just zero, which is a trivial function of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

An ordinary differential equation $F(t, y, y' \ldots, y^{(n)}) = 0$ is **linear** if $F$ is an affine function of $y, y', \ldots, y^{(n)}$, or, equivalently, if it can be written in the form
$$a_n(t) y^{(n)}(t) + \cdots + a_1(t) y'(t) + a_0(t) y(t) = b(t)$$
for some coefficient functions $a_0, \ldots, a_n, b$ of $t$. (I think this is what you mean by "occur linearly".)

In you case $n = 3$ and $a_2(t) = 0$. In particular there's nothing wrong with a "missing term" $a_k(t) y^{(k)}(t)$---we can just take the coefficient to be the zero function.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I initially thought that there couldn't be a missing term. Now I get it, thanks again mate!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found it useful.